# Extract regexp matches from a string

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I was trying to capture matches in a string using this:

```
$String = "Feb122013Jan222013";    
my @Matches = ($String =~ /((Jan|Feb)\d\d\d\d\d\d)/g);    
foreach (@Matches)
{
    printf("[$_]\n");
}
```

This would print the following.

```
[Feb122013]
[Feb]
[Jan222013]
[Jan]
```

How can I get rid of Jan and Feb printed ? i.e Assign only the entire regex match to array elements and ignore sub-matches ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `(?:Jan|Feb)` instead of `(Jan|Feb)`. See [`(?:pattern)` in `perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

> This is for clustering, not capturing; it groups subexpressions like `()`, but doesn’t make backreferences as `()` does.